# Prediction of data using regression for time series

Tags: matlab, time-series, libsvm, prediction

I try to prepare the data for regression with time series analysis. I use LIBSVM on Matlab

Say I have N days of price and I want to predict the next day's price. The training set X is thus a vector of vectors of length K, and the training set Y are like:

(DAY 1).....(DAY 2).....(DAY K)-------->DAY (K+1)

(DAY 2).....(DAY 3).....(DAY K+1)------>DAY (K+2)

(DAY 3).....(DAY 4).....(DAY K+2)------>DAY (K+3)

so on...

But the problem is: I assume the test data solution will give me the days of DAY (K+1),DAY (K+2),DAY (K+3). But it always fits the last day of Independent variables. (Here they are (DAY K), (DAY K+1), (DAY K+2)).

I tried to change the value of K but it didn't change.

To explain more: As an example, suppose we have the following univariate time series s :

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 =s[1]..s[9]

Windowizing using N=3  yields:

> [s[k−3], s[k−2], s[k−1]] →s[k]
>
> ⎢1  2  3 ⎢    ⎢4⎢
>
> ⎢2  3  4 ⎢    ⎢5⎢
>
> ⎢3  4  5 ⎢    ⎢6⎢
>
> ⎢.  .  . ⎢    ⎢.⎢
>
> ⎢6  7  8 ⎢    ⎢9⎢

But the problem is the result fits the vector 
             ⎢3⎥ 
             ⎢4⎥ 
             ⎢5⎥
            ...
             ⎢8⎥

I couldn't find where the problem is?

Comment: It's not a general problem, but probably a problem with your code. You should attach some of the code so we can understand where the problem is.

Comment: n=3
dataTrainIndependent=dataTrainIndependent(:,2);
dataTrainIndependentOrj=dataTrainIndependent;
dataTrainIndependent=dataTrainIndependent(1:end-n);
for i=1:n;
dataTrainIndependent=[dataTrainIndependent dataTrainIndependentOrj(1+i:end-(n-i),:)];
end;
dataTrainDependent(1:n,:)=[];
%%%%also same for test data and made scale here
cmd = ['-s 4 -t 2'];
model = svmtrain(dataTrainDependent, dataTrainIndependent, cmd);
[predictedValue, acc, dec] = svmpredict(dataTestDependent, dataTestIndependent, model);
[MSE DA CP CD]=calculate(dataTestDependent,predictedValue);

Comment: add code to the question, comments dont format it well

Comment: Without code it's hard to tell where problem is. One possibility is that the time-series is sufficiency difficult to predict that the best available estimate is the "persistence forecast", although that would not be the case if you tested it with the `1:9` example suggested in the question.